# Haskell - Finding undeclared variables

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

**AST:**

```
data AST = Nr Int | Sum AST AST | Mul AST AST | Min AST | If AST AST AST | 
Let String AST AST | Var String deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Hi! I need some help finding undeclared variables in the input. My problem is that I can't simply do it in my evaluator like so:

```
eval :: Env -> AST -> Int
eval env (Nr nr) = nr
eval env (Sum xs xss) = eval env xs + eval env xss
eval env (Mul xs xss) = eval env xs * eval env xss
eval env (Min xs ) = - eval env xs
eval env (If x xs xss) = if (eval env x == 0)
                then eval env xs
                else eval env xss
eval env (Let s xs xss) = eval ((s, (eval env xs)) : env) xss 
eval env (Var x) = case lookup x env of
    Just n -> n
    Nothing -> error ("Variable " ++ x ++ " is undeclared!")
```

If there are any undeclared variables I need to give an appropriate error containing a list of ALL undeclared variables either while parsing, or post process my AST before evaluating. And I'm not sure where to start. Here's an example of a parsed expression:

```
parse "let X = + 1 2 in * X + 2 - X"
    Let "X" (Sum (Nr 1) (Nr 2)) (Mul (Var "X") (Sum (Nr 2) (Min (Var "X"))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with types:

> If there are any undeclared variables I need to give an appropriate error containing a list of ALL undeclared variables either while parsing.

How about a function `eval` that will either give you list of the undeclared variables, or an `Int` (if there were no undeclared variables).

```
type Identifier = String

eval :: Env -> AST -> Either [Identifier] Int
```

We need to wrap raw numbers in a `Right` now:

```
eval env (Nr nr) = Right nr
```

The same for the a declared variable in the `Var` case,
while an undeclared variable gets wrapped in a list and a `Left`:

```
eval env (Var x) = case lookup x env of
    Just n -> Right n
    Nothing -> Left [x]
```

For the `Min` case, we can't just negate the recursive call anymore, since
negation isn't defined for `Either [Identifier] Int`.

We could pattern match to see what we got:

```
eval env (Min xs ) = case eval env xs of
  Left err -> Left err
  Right x  -> Right (-x)
```

But that's pretty wordy, and is exactly the same as using `fmap` from `Either e`'s functor instance:

```
eval env (Min xs ) = fmap negate (eval env xs)
```

Similarly for `Sum`, we could pattern match on both arguments:

```
eval env (Sum xs xss) = case (eval env xs, eval env xss) of
  (Left err, Left err') -> Left (err ++ err')
  (Left err, Right _)   -> Left err
  (Right _, Left err')  -> Left err'
  (Right a, Right b)    -> Right (a + b)
```

Note how if both subterms contain undeclared variables that we concatenate them to get the list of undeclared variables under the `Sum`.

This is the same trick we'll need for the rest of the constructors.  However, I don't want have to type out a huge `case` statement like that every time. That's a lot of work for a little addition!  And `If` and `Let` are going to have eight cases!

So let's make a helper function to do this for us:

```
apply :: Either [Identifier] (a -> b) -> Either [Identifier] a -> Either [Identifier] b
apply (Left err) (Left err') = Left (err ++ err')
apply (Left err) (Right _)   = Left err
apply (Right _)  (Left err') = Left err'
apply (Right f)  (Right a)   = Right (f a)
```

Now defining cases for `Sum`, `Mul`, and `If` is much easier:

```
eval env (Sum xs xss) = fmap (+) (eval env xs) `apply` eval env xss
eval env (Mul xs xss) = fmap (*) (eval env xs) `apply` eval env xss
eval env (If x xs xss) = fmap jnz (eval env x) `apply` eval env xs `apply` eval env xss
  where jnz i a a' = if i == 0 then a else a'
```

`Let` is slightly different:

```
eval env (Let s xs xss) = fmap second v `apply` eval env' xss
  where val = eval env xs
        env' = (s,val) : env
        getRight (Right a) = a
        getRight (Left _) = 0
        second _ a = a
```

Note how we "cheat" by providing a bogus value to the environment for the second term when the first term contains an undeclared variable. Since we're not going to be use any `Int` value the second term might yield in this case anyway, this is ok.

---

Once you get a bit further in Haskell, you might notice that `apply` looks a lot like `<*>` from `Applicative`. The reason we didn't just use that is that `Either e`'s `Applicative` instance doesn't work how we want it to. Instead of aggregating the errors, it quits when it hits the first one:

```
>>> Left ["foo"] `apply` Left ["bar", "baz"]
Left ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
>>> Left ["foo"] <*> Left ["bar", "baz"]
Left ["foo"]
```

However, there's the [`Validation` type from the `either` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-4.4.1.1/docs/Data-Either-Validation.html#t:Validation) that has an applicative instance that works exactly this way, so if you wanted, you could use that:

```
>>> Failure ["foo"] <*> Failure ["bar", "baz"]
Failure ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

---

One approach that might make the `Let` case less hacky would be to change the return type of `eval` from `Either [Identifier] Int` to `([Identifier], [(Identifier, Int)] -> Int)` - have it return a list of all the free variables in the expression, along with a way to evaluate the expression given a binding of those variables.

If we give that type a name:

```
data Result a = Result { freeVariables :: [Identifier], eval :: [(Identifier,Int)] -> a }
```

We can define `Functor` and `Applicative` instances for it:

```
instance Functor Result where
  fmap f (Result is g) = Result is (f . g)
instance Applicative Result where
  pure a = Result [] (const a)
  Result is ff <*> js fa = Result (is ++ js) (ff <*> js)
```

And use those to easily define a function to parse out the free variables and an eval expression:

```
parse :: AST -> Result Int
parse (Nr nr) = pure nr
parse (Sum xs xss) = (+) <$> parse xs <*> parse xss
parse (Mul xs xss) = (*) <$> parse xs <*> parse xss
parse (Min xs ) = negate <$> parse xs
parse (If x xs xss) = jnz <$> parse x <*> parse xs <*> parse xss
  where jnz a b c = if a == 0 then b else c
parse (Let s xs xss) = Result ks h
  where Result is f = parse xs
        Result js g = parse xss
        ks = is ++ delete s js
        h env = g ((s,f env):env)
parse (Var x) = Result [x] $ \env -> case lookup x env of
  Just n -> n
  Nothing -> error ("Variable " ++ x ++ " is undeclared!")
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I've never worked with Either before but I'm gonna try to use it in my solution.